# Delphi XE7 не могу найти компонент TNotificationCenter

Tags: delphi, delphi-xe

Можно его как то доустановить?

Не могу найти никакой инфы по этому, или просто криво установилась xe7 ?

Comment: А где вы его ищите если не секрет?

Comment: А он в xe7 должен быть? В Берлине он на вкладке System (я нашёл с помощью поиска в Tool Palette)

Comment: http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/Libraries/Berlin/en/System.Notification.TNotificationCenter Появилось начиная с Берлина. XE7 и XE8 не имеют этого компонента

Comment: такс, а этот берлин надо ставить или он обновиться может до него или просто выцепить может компонент?
может подскажите, есть компонент популярный, для уведомлений чтобы для винды подходило, и не сносить xe7, а лучше чтобы и на d7 работало

Comment: Попробуйте [Delphi Community Edition](https://www.embarcadero.com/products/delphi/starter). Возможно, там также имеется данный компонент.

Comment: А этот компонент не зависит случайно от других компонентов/библиотек/RTL, которых в xe7 или d7 тоже нет?

Comment: в JCL посмотрите или еще в каком нить опенсорсе.